# Need help formatting Hours, Minutes, and Seconds for a Phonegap/Cordova app. Working in Android but not ios .. getting Nan

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, time, phonegap

I don't use time features in javascript often but need a countdown of 24 hours. I thought I had it figured out when it worked in Android, but unfortunately in iOS it is returning the Nan. I have read all the stack questions I could but still cannot devise a way to make it work ... (maybe I need more coffee)

The server time is formatted like this
2020-07-11 01:00:13
It is a timestamp type with a current timestamp default in mySQL

I bring it into the app via json. Here is the code I have that works in android. (The purpose is to countdown 24 hours then delete

```
var timecount2 = new Date(obj.chat_time);
   
   var subtracttime = new Date("01 00:00:00");  // bascially 24 hours
   var remainingcount = Math.abs(subtracttime-timecount2);  // difference in milliseconds
   var finishedcount = new Date(remainingcount, "HH:mm:ss");
   var date = new Date(remainingcount); 

   //I break out each part so I can format it in a unique way
   var d = addZero(date.getDay());
   var h = addZero(date.getHours());
   var m = addZero(date.getMinutes());
   var s = addZero(date.getSeconds());

   //add a little function to add a trailing zero if needed
   function addZero(i) {
   if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i;
   }
   return i;
   }
```

That works great in android (although again I don't often work with date and time in javascript) but fails in iOS
Any suggesstions?

Comment: `01 00:00:00` that is not a valid value for the date constructor.  24hrs is just. 1000*60*60*24..

Comment: so var subtracttime = 1000*60*60*24 ?

Comment: The code you posted does not return anything, it's just declaring vars and one little function. Could you please clarify your example?

Comment: Sure .. the end result is <div> '+h+':'+m+':'+s+' remaining</div> The app polls the server every few minutes and the time lets the users know how long they have before a message is automatically deleted. In android it looks like 17:22:34 remaining (an example) but ios it is Nan:Nan:Nan

Comment: Yes, and for your date input to really make sure that gets parsed, try modifying it too -> `2020-07-11T01:00:13.000Z`

Comment: So every few minutes the app gets `obj.chat_time` which is remaining time? Or what? I'm sorry it's still not clear for me...

Comment: @kosh yeah. It gets the new time and deducts the time from the server time. Its basically a countdown timer.

Comment: @CJBroersma, in this case, if the app subtracts 24 hours from the received timestamp, it gets timestamp in the past (24 hours earlier) each time. Looks a bit confusing to me. Could you please elaborate more on your approach and add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: For sure, I guess we can take the timecount2 variable ... (I suppose the 24hour deduction was probably not needed ... thanks for the link) I want to break that down into hours, minutes and seconds. Then I want to display it on my app. The hours, minutes and seconds work fine in the android app, but come up as Nan in iOS. For some reason android works and iOS does not. This is the format of the time stamp in the database 2020-07-11 19:56:46